# xcode React-native: library not found for -lWebEngageBannerPush

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I am using macbook Apple M1 Pro chip.
Getting this error :

```
ld: library not found for -lWebEngageBannerPush
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

"react": "16.13.1", "react-native": "0.63", "react-native-webengage": "^1.2.8"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue. But there is some additional code to add to your podfile to fix linking errors when building in xCode on an M1 mac. It is to do with a linker problem with react-native and Swift libraries. See the react-native github issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31941)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I opend the terminal using rosetta mode and reinstalled the pod, it resolved the issue